# Graph Families that are easy to color

Tags: graphs, reference-request, colorings

What are the non-trivial graph families that have a known chromatic number, or an easy way (polynomial-time algorithm) to compute the latter.

Examples would be:

- Kneser graphs
- Chordal graphs

Do you know any other families?

**Motivation:**

We are looking for interesting classes on which we can test a proper coloring heuristic. This is why we wanted some graphs that are not so easy to color but in the same time have a known chromatic number so we can evaluate the quality of the heuristic.

Comment: As evidenced by Juho's answer, this question is rather broad. Why are you asking? What do you need such classes for?

Comment: @Raphael We are looking for interesting classes on which we can test a coloring heuristic. This is why we wanted some graphs that are not so easy to color but in the same time have a known chromatic number so we can evaluate the quality of the heuristic.

Comment: I suggest adding that context/motivation to the question.  I think it helps focus the question and improve the likelihood you'll get useful answers.  You can edit your question to include that information in it.

Comment: It's straightforward to model $k$-coloring as SAT/CSP too, so maybe solvability in polynomial time doesn't matter too much. The solvers should handle many cases easily.

Comment: @IssamT. Easy-to-colour graphs might not be a good test for your heuristic. In a sense, they're very special and not typical of general graphs. For example, what if your heuristic works well on easy-to-colour graphs (where you don't really need a heuristic to help you) but terribly on general graphs (where a heuristic would be really useful)? You'd then conclude that your heuristic is great when actually, it doesn't help at all.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I definitely agree... but then how to evaluate its quality?

Comment: @IssamT. Well, why not just compute the exact value of the chromatic number for the graphs as well? I guess it's fine even if it took minutes to compute it (but again, SAT/CSP solvers tend to be good here).

Comment: @juho thanks very much. I ll try that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whenever you are interested in a (well-known) graph invariant, it's a good idea to check out ISGCI first. Have a look at graphs that have [bounded chromatic number](http://www.graphclasses.org/classes/par_19.html), or graphs for which [computing the number is doable in polynomial time](http://www.graphclasses.org/classes/problem_Colourability.html).

To shortly summarize the above, one could highlight perfect graphs (a superclass of chordal graphs), and graphs of bounded treewidth.

Comment: Gee, that's... comprehensive.